# AngularJS $http.get returns undefined and $http() is not a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, coffeescript

I'm building an app to dynamically load and display data from a database in AngularJS, but when I try to access my API (using either $http() or $http.get()), I receive errrors.
$http.get() error: `TypeError: undefined is not a function`, $http() error: `TypeError: object is not a function`

This specific error occurs in the code to dynamically load navigation tabs.

The code for both in CoffeeScript:

```
p4pControllers.controller 'navCtrl', [
    '$routeParams'
    '$scope'
    '$http'
    ($http,$scope,$routeParams) ->
        $http(
        method:'GET'
        url:'http://p4p-api.snyx.nl/tables'
    ).success (data) ->
        $scope.tabs = data
        return
    return

    $http.get('http://p4p-api.snyx.nl/tables').success (data) ->
       $scope.tabs = data
       return
    return
]
```

Does anyone see what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When using the array notation for injecting dependencies, the order of the arguments is important:

In your code:

```
['$routeParams',
 '$scope',
 '$http',
 function ($http, $scope, $routeParams)  {
    // $http argument        ==> $routeParams
    // $scope argument       ==> $scope (by coincidence)
    // $routeParams argument ==> $http
}
```

So, basically, you are doing `$routeParams.get()`, but `$routeParams` has no method `get()` (nor is it a function itself).

Comment: Ah, wow, I had not thought of that. Thank you! Accepted your answer.

Comment: That's the hole point of array notation: the oobject passed as argument has nothing to do with the name of the argument, because argument names will be mangled by minifiers at some point. The objected represented by the argument depends solely on the string (which doesn't get minified) in the corresponding index of the array.

Comment: Ah, yes, that makes sense. I'm used to server-side and lower level programming, so this takes some getting used to. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: BTW, inline array notation is not the only way :) You can use "normal" arguments and DI by argument name, but you have to use special, Angular-aware minifiers (e.g. ngmin; but there are other tools as well).

Comment: this helped me too! :)